# SQL query for sorting on the column partial value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort on column's partial value.

**For example**, I've a table employee with columns(Code, Name). Format of the value of Code column is DEPT:SR_NO.

I need to sort the Code column's SR_NO value only.

The above scenario is just for example of the real time scenario.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest that you split the column into 2 columns in your table. Then, the query will be easy.

Comment: Is `SR_NO` supposed by be numeric?

Comment: Ya DEPT is alphabets & SR_NO is the numerics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, ':', 1) AS dept
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, ':', -1) AS sr_no
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        sr_no
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it helped. I finally used it like this: 
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(CODE,':',-1)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions, yes. You can also do something like `Order by Right(Name, Len(Name)-Instr(Name, ":"))` to pick up all the characters to the right of the colon and sort by that.